# Not able to save uploaded PNG file

Tags: php, upload, png

I'm able to  upload JPG files, but not PNG files.
The PNG image is not saved, but ouputs this `‰PNG    À À°£ûïS JÄž Ÿ¬™Ù<íû;`

My code is like this:

```
  $source_gd_image = imagecreatefrompng( $sourcefile ); // <-- If PNG file
  $target_gd_image = imagecreatetruecolor( $target_image_width, $target_image_height );

  if($source_image_type == IMAGETYPE_PNG) {
    imagealphablending($target_gd_image, true); // Should this be false?
    imagesavealpha($target_gd_image, true); 
    imagepng($target_gd_image); // <-- This is where the gibberish is outputed
  }

  if($source_image_type == IMAGETYPE_JPEG) {
    imagecopyresampled( $target_gd_image, $source_gd_image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $target_image_width, $target_image_height, $source_image_width, $source_image_height );
    imagejpeg( $target_gd_image, $target_file, $quality );
  }

  imagedestroy( $source_gd_image );
  imagedestroy( $target_gd_image );
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try adding `header('Content-type: image/png');` before output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just like with [`imagejpeg`](http://php.net/imagejpeg), you have to specify [a file name as the second parameter](http://php.net/imagepng) if you want to save it to a file, otherwise it just gets output to the browser.

Assuming $target_file is the desired output file name, that means using:

```
imagepng($target_gd_image, $target_file);
```

Comment: Ah! I always fail to understand the DOC `bool imagepng ( resource $image [, string $filename [, int $quality [, int $filters ]]] )` - but now that you say this, I can also add quality after `$target_file`.

Comment: @Steven: Indeed, brackets indicate optional elements - if you want to put $quality, you also have to put something for $filename. This notation is quite common in language documentation, so it's useful to know. Also note that since PNG is lossless, "quality" is really a misnomer; it sets the compression level, but that only affects the file size, not the actual image data.

Comment: The background is still black. I've tried setting `imagealphablending` to true and false, but I get the same result.

Comment: @Steven: You're never copying the image data to the target image. You need to use `imagecopyresampled` here as well.